# Python + Selenium: for loop went wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, for-loop

I am trying to get "href" of divs in for loop and enter the "href" in each "season".
It's working but after the first season, it's not finding the second season and next...

It's breaking in `season.get_attribute` after the first episode and not continue, I tried to fix it 3 hours.

If someone can help me, thanks in advance.

The URL : [http://www.tvil.me/view/181/1/1/v/הומלנד_Homeland.html](http://www.tvil.me/view/181/1/1/v/%D7%94%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%A0%D7%93_Homeland.html)

```
  seasons_num = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'change-season-')]/a")
    I = 0;
    for season in seasons_num:
        I += 1
        print("Season: %i" % (I))
        try:
            season_link = season.get_attribute("href") // It's breaks here
           ## seasons.append(season_link)
        except:
            print("---- Faild to fetch season %i -----" % (I))
            raise

        print("%s Season %i" % (post_id, I))
        driver.get(season_link)
        episodes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'change-episode-')]/a")
        E = 0;
        for episode in episodes:
            E += 1
            print("Post ID:%s Season:%i Episode: %i" % (post_id,I,E))
            time.sleep(1)
            episode_link = episode.get_attribute("href")
```

The response:

```
Post_ID: 100
Season: 1
100 Season 1
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 1
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 2
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 3
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 4
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 5
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 6
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 7
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 8
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 9
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 10
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 11
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 12
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 13
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 14
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 15
Post ID:100 Season:1 Episode: 16
Season: 2
```

**Failed to fetch season 2:**

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File C:\Users\maorb\OneDrive\Desktop\Maor\python\serethd\tvil.me.py", line 54, in <module> season_link = season.get_attribute("href")
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 112, in get_attribute
         resp = self._execute(Command.GET_ELEMENT_ATTRIBUTE, {'name': name})
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py",
 line 457, in _execute
         return self._parent.execute(command, params)
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
 line 233, in execute
         self.error_handler.check_response(response)
       File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
 line 194, in check_response
         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
     selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed
 since it was looked up
     Stacktrace:
         at fxdriver.cache.getElementAt (resource://fxdriver/modules/web-element-cache.js:9454)
         at Utils.getElementAt (file:///C:/Users/maorb/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp8gu_bklc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:9039)
         at WebElement.getElementAttribute (file:///C:/Users/maorb/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp8gu_bklc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12146)
         at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///C:/Users/maorb/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp8gu_bklc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
         at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///C:/Users/maorb/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp8gu_bklc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
         at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///C:/Users/maorb/AppData/Local/Temp/tmp8gu_bklc/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: **Please post the url..**

Comment: @AbdullahAhmedGhaznavi Updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python selenium trying to foreach elments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50026562/python-selenium-trying-to-foreach-elments)